# Como fazer um bypass em um redirecionamento HTTP?

Tags: php, redirecionamento

Existe alguma forma de fazer um "bypass" e acessar a página? Por exemplo:

```
if(!isset($variavel)) { 
  header ('Location: error.php');
} else {
  echo 'oi';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se você considera isto um *bypass*, mas a emissão do header não termina o script. Você deve fazer isso manualmente com [`exit`](https://www.php.net/exit) após um redirect, ou o script segue em frente:

```
if(!isset($variavel)) { 
  header ('Location: error.php');
  exit;
} else {
  echo 'oi';
}
// Chegaria aqui sem o exit
```

Se a sua dúvida é quanto à execução do `else` do seu código, isso não tem relação com o redirecionamento. Tudo depende de a variável `$variavel` estar definida ou não. Logicamente, se o código de redirecionamento do seu exemplo for executado, não tem como o `else` também ser executado.